# Scrolling Banno Digital Toolkit within Android Mobile App

Tags: android, css, mobile, scroll, banno-digital-toolkit

I’m running into a very perplexing issue with the Banno Plugin iFrame on Android devices only.  I’m unable to scroll within the iFrame.  Do you have any example code or guidance on how to make this work?  Below is the css that I’m using to show the scrollbar.  I’ve also set it to scroll so which typically shows the scrollbar at all times. It does work on iOS and any web browser including the mobile web browser.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the css that I'm using within the iFrame

```
height: 400px; 

overflow-x: hidden; 

overflow-y: auto;
   
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling in an iframe or embedded mobile browser is not ideal. But it should work with the following styles:

```
html, body { height: 100%; display: block; overflow: scroll; }
```

Comment: I updated my code with the suggested and it still doesn't scroll within the Android mobile app only.  Any other suggestions?  

If I'm unable to scroll, how do you suggest adjusting the height of the container iFrame, if the size of the content is unknown.  I'm open to suggestions on changes to the layout of the application.  I thought about tabs as a possible option too.

Comment: This may be a bug that has to be fixed on the Android app then.