# Messages UI does not scroll on Desktop or Android

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We have created our own alerts platform for Banno. We found in testing that large messages would not allow you to scroll on the android or desktop environments. Apple devices will allow you to scroll for larges messages in the messages portal.

Any thoughts that stick out for this? We have a Trello card open as well, since we are still in implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear from the question's description if you have built your own plugin card for the Banno Dashboard (see https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/getting-started/) or if you're talking about something else. Can you elaborate? If it's a plugin card then you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68086704/6680761 (which is similar). If it's not a plugin card, then you should talk to your Implementation Coordinator about opening up a case in jSource.

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. The issue that we are having is in regards to the alert being added to the Messages navigation, where Banno Native alerts reside as well as Banno Conversations. When we have our alert post to this same location as a message, the ability to scroll on longer messages goes away on desktop and android. Apple devices allow for the message to scroll. Does that clarify?

Comment: Oh, in that case that's not a Digital Toolkit topic per se, but sounds like it may be undesired behavior within Banno's UI itself. You should talk to your Implementation Coordinator about opening up a case in jSource since this is more of a _product_ question than a _developer_ question.