# Scrolling issue in android

Tags: android, css, banno-digital-toolkit

We have embedded our application inside of Banno using iframe and we are having issue with scrolling on Android devices. We have added the necessary css but nothing is working. It works fine on IOS and web platforms. Someone also mentioned a similar issue here. [Scrolling Banno Digital Toolkit within Android Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068167/scrolling-banno-digital-toolkit-within-android-mobile-app#new-answer?newreg=b4edff9fe2b147fdb56929a2ee94c33a)

Comment: After looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068167/scrolling-banno-digital-toolkit-within-android-mobile-app#new-answer?newreg=b4edff9fe2b147fdb56929a2ee94c33a, the Product direction is to _not_ support scrolling within a plugin's Card Face due to UX issues. While the scrolling may not be explicitly _restricted_ at this time, expect that we will update our guidance and docs to reflect the fact that plugin cards are not expected to support scrolling (i.e. it is what it is across platforms, subject to change as we button things up).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Our app has to scroll to view all the info, do you have any suggestions or workarounds for this?

Comment: Yes, our guidance is to use the Card Face for quick, summary info that is glanceable, and to use the Expanded View for more detail, content, and longer sessions. See the _"Designing and Developing Plugins"_ guide for more info: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please ignore the shade from the bot.